# globally disable enter/return key in a SWT dialog

Tags: java, swt

I've created a dialog class filling some common widgets, like text, combo, and tree. It annoys to have the default behavior to dismiss this dialog (same as the default 'OK' button is pressed) when enter/return is pressed whichever widget I was in.

To prevent this behavior, I have to add a traverse listener for each widget to filter the traverse key:

```
if (SWT::TRAVERSE_RETURN == event.detail) {
  event.doit = false 
}
```

This is somewhat annoying. Is there a way to globally do in the dialog level?

Comment: @bryantsai Thank you for your feedback: if you do solve this issue, do not forget to post an answer here (you will be able to select it as the official answer)

Answer (score 3):

I found that in a JFace dialog it's easy to disable default Enter Key by overriding method `createButtonsForButtonBar`.

and the last parameter of:

> createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID,IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL,
>   false);

needs to be false:

```
@Override
protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
Button button = createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID,
        IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg34561.html), this seems to be the only way, also illustrated by [Snippet127](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet127.java?view=markup&content-type=text%2Fvnd.viewcvs-markup&revision=HEAD) ("prevent Tab from traversing out of a control")

May be this [`Dialog` class](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.tm.rse/plugins/org.eclipse.rse.ui/UI/org/eclipse/rse/internal/ui/dialogs/SystemRenameDialog.java?root=DSDP_Project&view=co) illustrates a global use of a `TraverseListener` with their `keyTraversed()` method.

Comment: Just experimented with implementing TraverseListener in the dialog class, but it turns out the event would go to individual widget first, then 'maybe' go to the containing dialog (not sure, since I can't observe this behavior). Anyway, globally defining in dialog class doesn't seem to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set the default button to null (Shell#setDefaultButton(null)) to prevent the behaviour for the complete dialog, otherwise I guess you'll have to single out the widgets where you want to supress the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem, which seems to work so far, is to create an invisible disabled button and set it as the shell's default button. To avoid messing with the rest of the layout I created the button in the dialog's button bar using the parent passed to `createButtonsForButtonBar()`.

```
    final Button hiddenButton = new Button(parent, SWT.PUSH);
    hiddenButton.setVisible(false);
    hiddenButton.setEnabled(false);
    parent.getShell().setDefaultButton(hiddenButton);
```

Now, all the default selection events push that button. Which, as is desired, does nothing.

Comment: This is a pretty bad solution imho

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my answer is too late and maybe my solution was impossible at 2009... But anyway I post it.

This issue can be solved with `Display.addFilter`. You have to add filter for traverse event somewhere in the beginning of your program.

```
Display.getDefault().addFilter( SWT.Traverse, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
        if( SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN == event.detail ) {
            System.out.println( "Global SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN" );
            event.doit = false;
        }
    };
} );
```

Later You create dialog and its default button doesn't work:

```
Shell shell = new Shell( SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL );
shell.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
shell.setSize( 250, 100 );

Label loginLabel = new Label( shell, SWT.NONE );
loginLabel.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false ) );
loginLabel.setText( "Login" );

Text text = new Text( shell, SWT.BORDER );
text.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false ) );

Composite buttonsContentComposite = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
buttonsContentComposite.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 2, 1 ) );
buttonsContentComposite.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );

Button okButton = new Button( buttonsContentComposite, SWT.PUSH );
okButton.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, true, false ) );
okButton.setText( "Ok" );
okButton.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent e ) {
        System.out.println( "Ok" );
    };
} );

Button cancelButton = new Button( buttonsContentComposite, SWT.PUSH );
cancelButton.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false ) );
cancelButton.setText( "Cancel" );
cancelButton.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent e ) {
        System.out.println( "Cancel" );
    };
} );

shell.setDefaultButton( okButton );

shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if( !Display.getCurrent().readAndDispatch() ) {
        Display.getCurrent().sleep();
    }
}
```

Filter catches traverse event and disallow sending it to the shell so default button will not work.
But this solution have one nuance - You can add Traverse listener for the shell and override the global filter effect:

```
shell.addTraverseListener( new TraverseListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTraversed( TraverseEvent event ) {
        event.doit = true;
    }
} );
```

This listener enable event back and default button will triggered.